# Rollover Images in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, web

Hi I have a fairly basic task, but cant seem to find the right answer to,

I'm making a set of buttons, you put the mouse over them and they change to a different image, take mouse off, change back...

It works fine in Safari, IE, Chrome,

Get into firefox and 4 don't work, randomly, not in any sort of order...

main.php - 
news.php - 
estore.php - 
contact.php

all dont work, all the images are double checked

Can't for the life of me figure this one out due to the inconsistency of the issue

Any help would be great cheers

```
      <a href="main.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="menuHomeNot.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="menuHome.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="menuHomeNot.jpg"' alt="Home"/></a> 
        <img src="menuBreaker.jpg" alt=" "  /> 
      <a href="news.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="menuNewsNot.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="menuNews.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="menuNewsNot.jpg"' alt="News" /></a> 
        <img src="menuBreaker.jpg" alt=" "  /> 
      <a href="membership.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="menuMembershipNot.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="menuMembership.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="menuMembershipNot.jpg"' alt="Membership" /></a> 
        <img src="menuBreaker.jpg" alt=" "  /> 
      <a href="registration.php" target="mainFrame"><img src="menuRegNot.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="menuReg.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="menuRegNot.jpg"' alt="Registration" /></a> 
        <img src="menuBreaker.jpg" alt=" "  /> 
      <a href="links.php" target="mainFrame"> <img src="menuLinksNot.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="menuLinks.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="menuLinksNot.jpg"' alt="Links" /></a> 
        <img src="menuBreaker.jpg" alt=" "  /> 
      <a href="loginpage.php" target="mainFrame"> <img src="menuLoginNot.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="menuLogin.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="menuLoginNot.jpg"' alt="LogIn" /></a> 
        <img src="menuBreaker.jpg" alt=" "  /> 
      <a href="committee.php" target="mainFrame"> <img src="menuCommitteeNot.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="menuCommittee.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="menuCommitteeNot.jpg"' alt="Committee" /></a> 
        <img src="menuBreaker.jpg" alt=" "  /> 
      <a href="estore.php" target="mainFrame"> <img src="menuEStoreNot.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="menuEStore.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="menuEStoreNot.jpg"' alt="E-Store" /></a> 
        <img src="menuBreaker.jpg" alt=" "  /> 
      <a href="guestbook.php" target="mainFrame"> <img src="menuGuestbookNot.jpg" onMouseOver="this.src='menuGuestbook.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='menuGuestbookNot.jpg'" alt="Guestbook" /></a> 
        <img src="menuBreaker.jpg" alt=" "  /> 
      <a href="contact.php" target="mainFrame"> <img src="menuContactNot.jpg" onmouseover='this.src="menuContact.jpg"' onmouseout='this.src="menuContactNot.jpg"' alt="Contact" /></a>
```

Comment: What do you mean *"4 don't work"*?

Comment: four pictures as buttons don't change images on mouseOver as they do in all other browsers, and as the other buttons do in firefox

Comment: there seems to be quite a few posts around about this, but no one ever posts their solution... If anyone has come across a similar firefox issue

Comment: Why not use CSS? http://www.elated.com/articles/css-rollover-buttons/

Comment: The order you declare the CSS anchor pseudo classes is important http://hungred.com/useful-information/css-priority-order-tips-tricks/

Answer (score 1):

try turning off cache, also I'd do this with css

Answer (score 1):

CSS `:hover` is the way to go.

If you really want to do it in JavaScript, give each image an ID and assign functions to each of the two events. Since the image filenames are closely related (You only add "Not" at the end), a pair of functions would serve you well and avoid repetition.

Don't use shortcuts. Use:

```
document.getElementById('your_id').setAttribute('src', 'image.jpg')
```

AFAIK It's the only standard way to reliably refer to HTML entities and their properties. The [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) keyword can make things shorter, but you might as well avoid it until you're more familiar with some of its perks.

Answer (score 0):

A better and more efficient way to do this would to be use CSS Sprites.

```
.footer-btn {
background-image:url("http://inyourclosetnyc.com/wp-content/themes/inyourcloset/images/footer-btn.png");
border:0;
display:block;
height:26px;
text-indent:-9999px;
width:78px;
}


.footer-btn:hover{
 background-position:0 -26px;   
}
```

You can see a live demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mirza/fcg8y/)